# Can't change logo & custom welcome msg after upgrade from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3

Tags: theme

I've updated my magento install from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3. After that, for some reason, my logo and custom welcome message are gone, and I can't change them.

As you can see, I have added a logo and a custom welcome message:
[image: screenshot]

But they are not shown on the website:
[image: screenshot]

what I have tried in the meantime:
- Flushed all cache multiple times
- Updated Porto theme to the latest version (including 2.1.x patch)
- run php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL

But no luck...

Anyone could help me and has an idea what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a know issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7949